# SQL Query to find start date time, end date time, time difference and last row of a particular ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below

| ID | DateTime | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-21 19:03:30.783 | XSR |
| 1 | 2022-06-21 19:04:40.763 | GKE |
| 1 | 2022-06-21 19:05:35.483 | ERE |
| 2 | 2022-07-20 11:01:20.783 | BMR |
| 2 | 2022-07-20 12:03:39.142 | PER |

It should produce an output as below. ie start datetime and end datetime of every ID. Also output the end time's Summary value.

**Expected Result**:

| ID | Start DateTime | End DateTime | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-21 19:03:30.783 | 2022-06-21 19:05:35.483 | ERE |
| 2 | 2022-07-20 11:01:20.783 | 2022-07-20 12:03:39.142 | PER |

Code I tried

```
select MIN (t1.DateTime) as StartTime, MAX (t1.DateTime) as EndTime, datediff(MINUTE, min(t1.DateTime), max(t1.DateTime)) as 'RunTime (Mins)'
,max (t1.Summary)
from table t1
```

Comment: What is your question here; you don't appear to ask anything. What is the difficulty you are having getting the results you want?

Comment: trying to get the start and end date/time along with the summary value of the end time. example of the resultant table (refer the second table).

Comment: Have a look at [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) and the `MIN` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  MIN(t1.[datetime]) AS [Starttime],
  MAX(t1.[datetime]) AS [Endtime],
  MAX(t2.summary) AS [Summary]
FROM Table t1, Table t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t2.[datetime] = (SELECT 
                         MAX([datetime]) 
                       FROM Table t3
                       WHERE t2.id = t3.id)
GROUP BY t1.id
;
```

Comment: Thank you Frank.
May be, I did not give my requirement right. All I need is, 
I have table (refer the first table in my initial post) which has multiple time entries for the same [ID], I need the output as first  and last date time for each ID along with last date time's Summary value.
result of the query should produce output as second table.

Comment: Hi Manikandan, I don't understand this comment. When I execute my query using your data, I get the results you want.
id Starttime Endtime Summary
1 2022-06-21 19:03:30.783 2022-06-23 19:05:35.483 ERE       
2 2022-07-20 11:01:20.783 2022-07-20 12:03:39.143 PER

Comment: I see you are referencing 2 tables 
`FROM Table  **t1**, Table **t2**`
actually, in my case, I have 1 table

Comment: I'm not referencing 2 tables. I'm referencing 1 table twice. You didn't give a tablename so I named the table 'Table" in my SELECT-statement. I'm referencing "Table" twice so I had to use aliasses (t1 and t2).

Comment: Thank you Frank. Yes, your query is exactly producing the output which I was looking for. Sorry, initially I was little confused coz of the aliases. Cheers!